# Object removal in After Effects via Content-Aware?

Tags: after-effects, cleaning

I have footage from a drone, and there's a rather unsightly floating thing that I'd like to remove. I've heard that one could export this video as frames and use Photoshop's built in "Content-Aware" function to remove an object like this, but there's quite a few frames to work with here (and it's a rather complex object), so it doesn't seem completely feasible to do just that.

[image]

Here's a link to a GIF: [Hosted on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtEGt.jpg)

I'd like to know if there's an easier way to do this (Maybe via plugins if necessary). Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome George :) "Content-Aware" for every frame isn't a option since the algorithm produces a different solution per frame. I'd recommend to *track this part of the image and replace it* by a part next to it (left or right or should give best results, because of the camera movement and the floating sea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest that you try [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) for this?  It's free, and has a fantastic "clone stamping"-style tool, called Node Sizing  - see "Example 2: Using Node Sizing to duplicate a windowed area of an image to cover a blemish" p638 in the manual:
http://software.blackmagicdesign.com/DaVinciResolve/docs/DaVinci_Resolve_11_Manual_June_2014.pdf

It allows you to clone one region of a video over another, and to feather the edges. You can track the positions of moving items too - it's remarkably effective.

Update: After Effects now has content aware fill for video: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/content-aware-fill.html